# getting a partial to refresh without refreshing the whole page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

The problem is that i have created a partial that is rendered fine however i want to update it without having to update the rest of the page.This is my current code:

**rolls_controller:**

```
def check_server
    Roll.find(params[:id]).update(:status=> "Checked")

    render :update, :template => 'roll_calls/show' do |page|
        replace_html 'roll', Roll.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

**show.html.haml(relevant part)**

```
   - @roll_call.rolls.each do |r|
        .roll{ :id=> "roll" }
        =render(:partial=>"roll", :locals=>{ :r=>r })
```

sorry if this is not enough information to help me out(first post) but i am happy to post anything else

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple ajax. Your partial will be replaced in any division you want. Please follow below link:

https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

Hope it will work for you.